# Find and attach file from specific cell value

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

Is is possible to change the cell value from column `C` to `A24`? Currently, my file name location is column `C` and I've end up changing it to A24 and onward.

If anyone can suggest a simpler way to change the location would be really appreciate.

My current code is listed below.

```
Set obMail = Outlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
With obMail
.To = "email@comapny.com"
.Subject = "O/S Blanace"
.BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
.Body = "Please see attached files"

Do While Cells(irow, 3) <> Empty
    'pikcing up file name from column C
    pfile = Dir(dpath & "\*" & Cells(irow, 3) & "*")
    'checking for file exist in a folder and if its a pdf file

    If pfile <> "" And Right(pfile, 3) = "pdf" Then
        .Attachments.Add (dpath & "\" & pfile)
    End If

    'go to next file listed on the C column
    irow = irow + 1
Loop

.Send
End With
```

Comment: Are you now wanting to loop column A not C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value to use for the file name is now in Column A not C change

```
Cells(irow, 3)
```

to

```
Cells(irow, 1)
```

The second part is the columns argument and column A is number 1 on the sheet.

```
Cells(row,column)
```

Overall with the code see the following:

1) `Option Explicit` at the top to make sure all variables are declared, that the typing is consistent and your spelling is consistent.

2) Put those declarations in. Note that a reference to the Outlook Object Library must be added if you are going to use early binding. Early binding will be quicker but will hit problems if someone else using your program has a different version of Outlook.

3) Set the scope of the procedure e.g. I can't see the signature for your sub so I will assume it is called as public i.e. can be called from other modules. So for my test example I am putting:

```
 Public Sub test()
```

4) `iRow` needs somewhere to start and it can't be 0 , which is what it is instantiated as. There is no 0 row in the sheet. Long type variables and Integers (I couldn't see a declaration so I went with Long). For the why, see the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long). It is certainly a safer bet as with Integer you run the risk of overflow. You would set this to the start row for where you want to commence looping. In your case row 24.

5) That loop..... you have a number of options:

You could also consider:

```
 Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(irow, 1))
```

This will stop at the first empty cell. Notice that I have explicitly stated which sheet is being worked with via `ActiveSheet.Cells` rather than implicitly calling by `Cells`. Better still would be to use the actual sheet name.

Or, if you know that all the cells will be populated up to an including row N in column A you could put:

```
 Do Until irow  = N + 1
```

I am less of a fan of the second. There are lots of other ways to construct your loop but essentially you want to look for the **earliest viable exit**.

6) Use `vbNullString` rather than the empty string literal "" 
   i.e.  `pfile <> vbNullString` rather than `pfile <> ""`. 
   It is faster to assign, more efficient and generally what you want to use.

7) If you really did want easy access to the start row and column you could have them as public constants. In which case you would declare them at the top of the module after the `Option Explicit` like so:

```
Public Const startRow As Long = 24
Public Const columnToLoop As Long = 1
```

You would then refer to them in the code as

`Cells(iRow, columnToLoop)` rather than `Cells(irow, 1)`

and

`irow = startRow` rather than  `irow = 24`

So in summary you could have something like:

```
Option Explicit
Public Const startRow As Long = 24
Public Const columnToLoop As Long = 1

Public Sub test()

    Dim ObMail As MailItem
    Dim irow As Long
    Dim dPath As String
    Dim pfile As String

    dPath = vbNullString 'what are your values
    pfile = vbNullString 'what are you values

    Set ObMail = Outlook.CreateItem(OlMailItem)

    irow = startRow

    With ObMail
        .To = "email@comapny.com"
        .Subject = "O/S Blanace"
        .BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
        .Body = "Please see attached files"

        Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(irow, columnToLoop))
            'picking up file name from column A

            pfile = Dir(dPath & "\*" & Cells(irow, columnToLoop) & "*")
            'checking for file exist in a folder and if its a pdf file

            If pfile <> vbNullString And Right(pfile, 3) = "pdf" Then
                .Attachments.Add (dPath & "\" & pfile)
            End If

            'go to next file listed on the A column
            irow = irow + 1
        Loop

        .Send '.Display 'for testing purposes
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: would it be possible to add sub-folders search in this? script? I can find the file from main location but if its under sub folders it doesn't recognize

Answer (score 0):

I believe you’re after this

```
Set obMail = Outlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
With obMail
    .To = "email@comapny.com"
    .Subject = "O/S Blanace"
    .BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
    .Body = "Please see attached files"

    irow= 24 ‘initialize row index from 24
    Do While Cells(irow, 1) <> Empty
        'pikcing up file name from column A
        pfile = Dir(dpath & "\*" & Cells(irow, 1) & "*")
        'checking for file exist in a folder and if its a pdf file

        If pfile <> "" And Right(pfile, 3) = "pdf" Then
            .Attachments.Add (dpath & "\" & pfile)
        End If

        ‘go to next file listed on the A column
        irow = irow + 1
    Loop

    .Send
End With
```

Comment: would it be possible to add sub-folders search in this? script? I can find the file from main location but if its under sub folders it doesn't recognize.